# Can I install Python locally on Windows regardless of whether or not a copy is already installed elsewhere?

Tags: python, windows

I am bundling python with software to be distributed with windows. I would like to install python locally during the install process. However, I notice that if the user has a copy of python already installed elsewhere, the install window will not pop up and instead I get the window shown below.

This happens even if I set InstallAllUsers=0 TargetDir=<local_dir> /quiet etc etc in a cmd terminal. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question. The Python website supplied embedded zip files for the purpose of embedding python in an application.